# MySQL table with a lot of text

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

So I have this database (Size 3.1Gb total), but this is due to one specific table I've got, containing A LOT of console output text, from some test runs. The table itself is 2.7Gb, and I was wondering if there could be another solution for this table, so the database would get a lot smaller? It's getting a bit anoying to backup the database or even make a copy of the database to a playground, because it's so big this table.

The Table is this one

[image]

Would it be better to delete this table and make all the **LogTextData** <- *LongText*, be stored in a **PDF**, instead of the database? (Then I can't backup this data tho...)
Do anyone have an idea on how to make this table smaller, or another solution? I'm open for suggestions, to make this table smaller.

The way this console log data gets imported to the database is by **Python scipts**, so I have fully access to other python solutions, if there is any.

Comment: A PDF wouldn't exactly save space, I would suggest using actual log files (in plain text) and then using compression on them. Either way this is not a programming question

Comment: @OferSadan Do you have a idea on how to make a backup on this content? I could each day make a **gzip** of all the created logfiles, and then transfer them to another location (Cloud)? The database already gets transfered to another location, IF the server breaks, so no data is lost.

Comment: Yes, gzip old logs is a good solution (either daily or on another schedule, up to you) and it would not take up any database space in that case (but will take file space of compressed files, which would probably be much less)

Comment: This is all true BTW if and only if you don't need to access this content regularly on your database of course. I suggest asking again on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OferSadan Thats true, this data is being access regular ..

Answer (score 0):

You could try enabling either the [Storage-Engine Independent Column Compression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/storage-engine-independent-column-compression/#comparison-with-innodb-page-compression) or [InnoDB page compression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-page-compression/). Both provides ways to have a smaller on-disk database which is especially useful for the large text fields.

Since there's only one table with one particular field that's taking up space, trying out individual column compression seems like the easiest first step.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should just store the path of log files instead of the complete logs in the database. By using those paths you can access the files anytime you want.

It will decrease the size of database too.

Your new table would look like this,
LogID, BuildID, JenkinsJobName,LogTextData.

Comment: But by storing the path of the logs I dont get a backup of the files itself? I need to make sure that all files are backed up, and not lost. At the moment the MySqlDumps is uploaded to a cloud server, so I can always run a MySQL import and rebuild the database, but it takes forever since the database is 3.2Gb